# File .aspx - HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it

Tags: asp.net

I went to Framework4.0 and ran aspnet_regiis -i but it  didn't change a thing
In inetmgr I went to isapi and web restrictions and set everything to allow.

Perhaps a clue to the problem might be that the file handler which is not registered is a .aspx file.

It stopped working without me changing anything.

The page launched in my browser from VS2013 is  http://localhost:2562/Default.aspx

Perhaps some additional info might do:
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:2562/Default.aspx
Physical Path      C:\temp\ASP.Net\Doratletica\Default.aspx
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\parena\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\DORATLETICA

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to system.web.compilation section of your web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".aspx" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"  />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```